Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: CreateService error: Access denied
I am creating a cloud formation stack for ECS but getting this access denied error and my stack fails.

ERROR: Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: CreateService error: Access denied (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: c894016a-395d-4468-92fa-b63a2a4642f9; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: 5d151803-6b53-02ea-8903-7c34934b251e, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest)


I have tried using multiple solutions available on internet but none of this works for me. i even tried creating a separate  ExecutionRole but its gave the same error. i have tried creating same stack in my personal account using root user and its works. but when I am login as a IAM user it gives access denied error.
i am using nested stack. here is my root.yaml file you can try in your account.
root.yaml: https://cloudformation-exam-paranjay.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/exam2/root.yaml
ECS.yml
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: The template used to create an ECS Service from the ECS Console.
Parameters:
  ECSClusterName:
    Type: String
    Default: ecs-tutorial
  ECSServiceName:
    Type: String
    Default: ecs-tutorial-td
  LoadBalancerName:
    Type: String
    Default: ecs-tutorial-lb
  WAFName:
    Type: String
    Default: AllowAllTrafficAcl

Resources:
  ECSService:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
    Properties:
      Cluster: ecs-tutorial
      CapacityProviderStrategy:
      - CapacityProvider: FARGATE
        Base: 0
        Weight: 1
      TaskDefinition: !Ref TaskDefinition #arn:aws:ecs:us-east-1:818971154557:task-definition/ecs-tutorial-td:1
      ServiceName: ecs-tutorial-td
      # SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      DesiredCount: 2
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: tindog
        ContainerPort: 80
        LoadBalancerName:
          Ref: AWS::NoValue
        TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: TargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          # AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups: !Split [",", !ImportValue ECSSecurityGroup]
          Subnets:
            - !ImportValue PrivateSubnet1Id
            - !ImportValue PrivateSubnet2Id
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
    DependsOn:
    - Listener

  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    Properties:
      Family: tindog-website-family
      # TaskRoleArn: !ImportValue ECSTaskRoleARN  # Import the IAM role ARN from another stack
      Cpu: 512 #0.5cpu
      Memory: 1024  #1gb
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      # ExecutionRoleArn: !ImportValue ECSTaskRoleARN 
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: tindog
          Image: paranjay1/tindog:latest
          PortMappings:
            - ContainerPort: 80

      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - EC2
        - FARGATE

  LoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Type: application
      Name: ecs-tutorial-lb
      SecurityGroups: !Split [",", !ImportValue ECSSecurityGroup]
      Subnets:
        - !ImportValue PublicSubnet1Id
        - !ImportValue PublicSubnet2Id

  TargetGroup:
    DependsOn: LoadBalancer
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      HealthCheckPath: "/"
      HealthCheckProtocol: HTTP
      Name: ecs-tutorial-target-group
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: !ImportValue VPCID
      TargetGroupAttributes:
      - Key: deregistration_delay.timeout_seconds
        Value: '300'

  Listener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - Type: forward
        TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: TargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: LoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: HTTP

  MyWAFWebACL:
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACL
    DependsOn: LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: !Ref WAFName 
      Scope: REGIONAL
      DefaultAction:
        Allow: {}  # An empty Allow block allows all traffic 
      VisibilityConfig:
        CloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true  # Enable CloudWatch metrics collection
        MetricName: MyWafMetric  # Define a metric name for WAF logs
        SampledRequestsEnabled: true  # Enable capturing a sample of requests for analysis

  MyWAFWebACLAsgn:
    DependsOn: MyWAFWebACL
    Type: AWS::WAFv2::WebACLAssociation
    Properties:
      WebACLArn: !GetAtt MyWAFWebACL.Arn
      ResourceArn: !Ref LoadBalancer
  
Outputs:
  ClusterName:
    Description: The cluster used to create the service.
    Value:
      Ref: ECSClusterName
  ECSService:
    Description: The created service.
    Value:
      Ref: ECSService
  LoadBalancer:
    Description: The created load balancer.
    Value:
      Ref: LoadBalancer
  Listener:
    Description: The created listener.
    Value:
      Ref: Listener
  TargetGroup:
    Description: The created target group.
    Value:
      Ref: TargetGroup
  LoadBalancerDNSName:
    Description: The DNS name of the load balancer.
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.DNSName
    Export:
      Name: LoadBalancerDNSName
  LoadBalancerARN:
    Description: "ALB ARN"
    Value: !GetAtt LoadBalancer.LoadBalancerArn
    Export:
      Name: "LoadBalancerARN"

I am using IAM user and I have the following permission attached to IAM user


You could try making it from the console manually and see what complains - the error will probably be more informative.

You're using CFN to create ECS, however, i don't see that you have permission related to CFN. Let's try to add CFN permission create resource and any other related, you can checkout this page to see which permission that you may need https://aws.permissions.cloud/iam/cloudformation#cloudformation-CreateResource

I have assigned the AWSCloudFormationFullAccess policy to my IAM user. still giving the same error.
